# Bash: Getting a command's completion output programmatically (e.g., in a variable)

Tags: bash, shell, tab-completion

How to tap into the completion of another command programmatically?

Supposing my current directory has files `a1`, `a2`, and `a3`, then how can I make my command invoke the autocompletion of `ls a` to get back `a1 a2 a3`?

Is this possible?

---

**Clarification and justification**:

I chose `ls` because people can relate to it. It is a contrived example that is intentionally simple so that people can understand the question without distractions, but unfortunately such examples sometimes take us on tangents. :)

Let me try to exemplify the value of this feature. I have a command called `build` which, given a directory, can autocomplete to the targets that can be built in that directory. Those targets may not correspond to the files from that directory, and so glob completion (* and other wildcard characters) will not work. The targets might be mined by the `build` command from a build file that I don't want to be parsing. In other words:

`build path/to/dir/`<kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

Might give:

```
path/to/dir/a_target
path/to/dir/b_target
```

Again, a_target and b_target are not files or directories.

`build` is a pre-existing command, not something I can go ahead and modify to suit my purposes. And the manner in which it comes up with the valid completions is something I certainly don't want to know or reinvent.

Now suppose I have an entire repository of `build`able projects, and most of my work and therefore most of my `build` work happens in only one project. In other words, I always `build` targets under `my/project/directory`.

So far so good.

I want to write a wrapper around the build command that doesn't require me to feed it the directory path each time I run it. I want it to know my preferred project directory (or directories, why not) and let me reference the targets without qualifying them:

So under the assumption that I have:

```
my/project/directory/a_target
my/project/directory/b_target
```

I want this:

`mybuild` <kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd>

to give me:

```
a_target
b_target
```

Basically I want to decorate and simplify the behavior of `build` to suit my particular needs.

I will need to write my own completion code for `mybuild`, but I want it to rely on the completion for `build`, because I can't ask the developers of `build` to code a `build listtargets` command just to make me happy. (Although that would be much more robust.) The `build` command already has code somewhere that given a prefix can return all the matching targets. It's in the completion for `build`, and I need to tap into it.

(Of course, when I run `mybuild a_target`, I will make sure that it knows to run `build my/project/directory/a_target`. I know how to implement this and it is not in scope for this question.)

I hope this illustrates why I need to tap into the completion of the `build` command and invoke it as a black box.

Comment: Why do you think that you need to automate this interactive feature of the shell?  What are you trying to do? (`ls a*` will give you a list of all files starting with 'a'.)

Comment: See my newly added justification.

Comment: You can define your own completions for `mybuild` in `bash`, so that tab-completion will only suggest files that exist in a directory specified by some environment variable. I would suggest reading up on programmable completion in the `bash` man page (it's not the clearest documentation, but give it a try), and ask again after you've made a first try at coding it.

Comment: The completion for the `build` command doesn't work with files. It extracts build targets from some make file. I will define my own completion, but it needs to use `build`'s completion to know what targets to present me with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of an odd thing to do, and the command you need to execute depends on the number of files in the directory - none, one, or more than one. But this command works for the example case:

```
echo echo a$'\t'$'\t' | bash -i 2>&1 | head -3 | tail -1
```

The command being autocompleted is

```
echo a
```

so send that as a character stream, followed by two tab characters, into an interactive bash shell. `bash` produces the autocompletion output on `stderr`, so redirect that to `stdout` and pipe that through `head` and `tail` to select one line of output from the whole. That produces, in this case, the one-line output

```
a1  a2  a3
```

But, as others say, just using

```
echo a*
```

might be easier!

Comment: That's cool!  You can say `echo l$'\t\ty' | bash -i` to get a list of commands starting with `l` also. I'm not sure how that is useful... yet :D

Comment: It hasn't worked in my initial testing, but I will sit on it to see if I can make it work. The question isn't about completing files. It's about completing anything. That's why I need to tap into the completion of a given command. My specific command doesn't complete files -- it completes build targets extracted from a manifest file with a complex structure that (a) I can't reasonably parse in a shell script, and (b) I don't want to parse in a shell script because I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hmm, it does work, with a couple of caveats: 1. I should suppress the PS1 (perhaps starting bash with a special bashrc will do the trick), and 2. the shell should not also attempt to execute the command (perhaps if I can send a Ctrl+C -- didn't work in initial testing).

Comment: I can suppress PS1 by using `| PS1= bash -i`, but I haven't yet had luck in preventing the command from executing.

Comment: I'm trying this on an iMac having done 'brew install bash_completion', so your results may differ. But, I can only make command completion (as opposed to filename expansion) work in the login shell, not my subshell. If I _could_ make it work in the subshell, I could try out 'printf "PATH= brew ins\t" | bash -i' as a way of making command completion occur without executing. Certainly I can stop commands executing, but I can't make commands expand at the same time.

Comment: Interestingly, using `PS1=` (either on the `bash -i` or in the `echo`) trips the autocompletion, which now asks if it should display all possibilities. If I put a `y` in there, it seems to list all the files in my current directory. This occurs regardless of which variable I use in place of `PS1`.

Comment: I just found a way to prevent the command from executing: `echo if false\; then my_command $'\t'$'\t'\; fi | bash -i`. :D

Comment: Note that Ctrl+U (`$'\025')` can also be used in place of `if false` to prevent the command from executing. Then of course one has to figure out a way to get the footer string to be printed by Bash without being executed.

Comment: So here it is in all its glory. `echo if false\; then Header\; echo a$'\t'$'\t'y\; Footer fi | bash -i 2>&1 | sed -n '/Header/{:a;n;/Footer/q;p;ba}' | grep -v ^'Display all '`. The `sed` bit captures the lines between header and footer. Of course we'll want to use more sensible, unique names in place of `Header` and `Footer`. It is important not to filter the unnecessary line using line counting jiu-jistu assuming that PS1 is on a single line. I've seen a colleague with a two-line PS1. Also note the `y` which responds to the possible Bash question "display all possibilities?" :D

Comment: Is there no way to "capture" the internal variable `complete` uses to show the completion list?

Comment: @Peregring-lk: I would much prefer that over this automation solution. If you've found a way to do it, please share it (as an answer, even). See my other question on this topic that involves redirecting a command's completion to another command's completion. I don't think that helps here, because the script is not in the loop to postprocess the completion output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38936716/using-the-bash-autocompletion-of-another-command

Answer (score 1):

Bash has something similar to this called globbing.

So for example in your case you could run the command

```
echo a*
```

Which would produce:

```
a1 a2 a3
```

This is very useful where you have spaces in the names of your files as you can say

```
for i in a*
do
   echo $i
done
```

And it would work for `a1` as well as `a 1`

Comment: The thing is that command-specific completions are coded by someone and there is code somewhere that does the completion. I want to tap into that code. See my clarifications in the very question.

Answer (score 0):

Auto-completion is a feature provided by your shell (e.g. bash). The shell will try to offer auto-complete suggestions based on the context of the command you're trying to run and the environment. E.g. it knows that some commands will work on files and can offer some auto-completion based on file paths. But the command itself is not aware on how the arguments it has been run with have been specified, either by the user or with help of auto-completion.