# Using the Bash autocompletion of another command

Tags: bash, shell, autocomplete

When I create a command that wraps an existing command with some sugar, I'd like the new command to support the autocompletion of the original command. Is there a way to tell Bash to reuse the autocompletion script of another command?

Silly example:

```
cat > ~/ls-on-steroids.sh <<EOF
echo "Here are some goodies!"
ls "$@"
EOF
chmod +x ~/ls-on-steroids.sh
```

Now, how do I configure my new script such that when I type:

```
~/ls-on-steroids.sh <TAB><TAB>
```

I'd like the same behavior as with:

```
ls <TAB><TAB>
```

Preferably in a portable, repeatable manner, without having to manually track down the location of `ls`'s autocomplete script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure it manually, but it's relatively simple to copy completions from an existing command. First, run `complete -p ls` to see what, if any, command was defined for `ls`. If nothing comes up, `ls` doesn't use any special completions. You are probably expecting to see something like the following as the output, though

```
complete -o default -F _longopt ls
```

which says that the function `_ls` is called to generate completions for the command `ls`, and if the doesn't generate any results, use the `bash` default completion. You can apply the same function to `ls_on_steroids` by simply running

```
complete -o default -F _longopt ls_on_steroids
```

(i.e., replace `ls` with `ls_on_steroids` as the final argument in the command printed by `complete -p`).

Comment: That sounds like it could be automated. Any caveats though? Can that command look different on different systems? Is there a more direct way to get the name of the command that serves the autocomplete?

Comment: It looks like `complete` takes multiple commands, so I can just run: `complete -p ls | sed 's/$/ ls-on-steroids/` to include my script in `ls`'s autocompletion.

Comment: I meant: `$(complete -p ls | sed 's/$' ls-on-steroids/')`